# Interface not working

Tags: java, android, interface

I have used an interface to get the ArrayList from one class to other.But when ever i am calling the interface in other class i am not getting the value of ArrayList.

Interface

```
public interface GetArrayList {
    public void getArray(List<SearchModel> listValues);
}
```

Class where i am setting the arrayList

```
getArrayList = new GetArrayList() {
    @Override
    public void getArray(List<SearchModel> listValues) {
        listValues = values;
    }
};

JSONArray tableArray = NewDataSet.getJSONArray("Table");
for (int i = 0; i < tableArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject table = tableArray.getJSONObject(i);
    data = new SearchModel(/*Constructor irrelevant to question*/);
    values.add(data);
}
getArrayList.getArray(values);
```

Second Class where i want to use the arraylist

```
public class SearchJobList extends ListFragment {
    private View view;
    private List<SearchModel> data;
    private GetArrayList getArrayList;
    SearchJobAdapter jobAdapter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_job_list, null, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        data = new ArrayList<SearchModel>();
        getArrayList = new GetArrayList() {
            @Override
            public void getArray(List<SearchModel> listValues) {
                data = listValues;
                jobAdapter = new SearchJobAdapter(getActivity(), data);
                setListAdapter(jobAdapter);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `public ArrayList<SearchModel> getArrayList()`?

Comment: Sorry in dint get you???

Comment: Are you sending reference object of GetArrayList in Activity class to the one class which you are doing operation..?

Comment: I want to set the Adapter for the list.SO that i will be using the ArrayList,so thats y i haved used an interface

Answer (score 0):

try setting a static List  variable from mainActivity
 and try accessing it from the OtherActivity...

Comment: I know but using Static is good good programming way so i tried using interface

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Application" class. That's a little bit more to do but the right place to store global objects/data.

Each activity can access it by calling .getApplication(), just cast it to your inherited class.

In the AndroidManifest extend the "application" tag by the attribute "android:name" that specifies your own application class (extending Application).

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
             android:name="com.example.my.great.package.MyApplication"
....
```

The class:

```
class MyApplication extends android.app.Application {
....
```

Using in an activity:

```
((MyApplication)getApplication()).getMyList();
```